# Combining OSM data with non-opensouce data

Tags: qgis, license

Can I use OSM data and combine it with non-opensource data for commercial usage (in this case: an expert report)?

Example:

A picture in the report is showing an OSM basemap and data I calculated partly from OSM data, partly from closed sources (p. e. I use given maxspeed of streets and combine/multiply/divide it with vehicle load figures).

As far as I understand the OSM license, I am obliged to share generated data back to OSM. At this point I am pretty sure that the data I generated is of no interest for OSM and there is not possibility to input that data. Also the second source does not allow me to share the calculated data as part of the contract that gave me access to their data.

The license (and the case, @mapperz referred to) states, that I have to share my data. Do I need to upload it somehow? As there is no input possibility - where?

How do I give attribution in my report?

Comment: Answer from the Official source: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/License/Use_Cases#Case_4:_I_want_to_publish_something_based_on_OSM_and_some_data_I_obtained_elswhere

Comment: Thank you for pointing there, this is where I came from, as it partly answers the third part of my question, but not the rest. I clarify my question.